# Need ideas on how to find the best email send frequency go get maximum desired action

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

I have got data which contains email id total times email has been send to him (frequerny) and desired action taken (read, clicked etc), non desired action taken(unsubscribed, etc), also count of no action taken which will be y= a-b-c.

Now I need to find a optimised frequency where

1. I expect to get best frequency of desired response or optimum frequency to send mail
2. Number of mails he should send in day hour or whatever. What kind of algorithm or whatever Is out there I can use. Please suggest. Is there any optimisation algo in ML or solution to such problems available.